# Is remote database access already possible in smartphones?

Tags: android, ios, database, delphi, remote-access

I learned that we have to build web services to communicate mobile apps with database servers. But that was a long time ago. Is it already possible for example, to open a connection with a remote Mysql database and query it, instead having to upload xml/json data to a REST server?

Comment: You can do that but you don't want to. Direct db connection over internet is a very bad idea

Comment: There are various reasons why you don't want to do this. Security being the biggest reason...

Comment: A lot of hackers out there love to find direct database connections - having any database of any kind published on the internet is just asking for trouble.

Comment: But what if the connection is on an corporate intranet? Would that worth it?

Comment: The core of the problem is that it's not scalable. 1 year down the road and you'll be asked to make it available on the internet, and you'd have to re-write it.

Comment: The goal is to make an app to verify garage entrance. It would only work when the user comes close to the wifi of the building.

Comment: If you want to risk it, that's up to you. Even opening on WiFi can be dangerous. Actually MS SQL Server explicitly disables external access and firewall rules, and you have to go enable them yourself. Security has changed a lot in the past years.

Comment: is there DataSnap in Android? https://datasnapperformance.wordpress.com/